# How to get some form of connection to a server without monitor & keyboard

Tags: networking, ssh, installation

I need a way to connect to my server (HP ProLiant DL360P G8) & install some sort of operating system or firmware that can let me SSH in and install my Linux ISO. But due to the quarantine I cannot get a compatible keyboard or monitor right now.

What I do Have:
-Laptop with Ethernet port & cable
-28 GB USB thumb drive
-Server has Ethernet ports & USB ports.
-And a USB mouse (I doubt it would be much use without a monitor)

So is there any way I can use the USB or Ethernet port to "inject" some form of OS or ssh tool onto the server that requires no keyboard or monitor to be setup? I would think there would be some way as large server farms setup servers without manual intervention but I haven't had any luck finding the tools. Any & all help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the iLO configured?

Comment: Im not sure. How could I check?

Comment: See source: https://github.com/HewlettPackard/PowerShell-ProLiant-SDK and https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/HPEiLOCmdlets/3.0.0.0 `powershell Install-Module -Name HPEiLOCmdlets` and use commandline: `powershell $server="10.0.10.102";$credential = Get-Credential;$I=Get-HPiLOServerInfo -Server @($server)  -Credential $credential -DisableCertificateAuthentication -Category FirmwareInfo -Verbose;$I.FirmwareInfo` @Keltari Hello old friend)